# Two for loops only one is showing

Tags: c

This program is not recognizing the second for loop.  It stops after printing the length.
Looking for this result:
41WH(
Size of Array: 5
4 - Yes, this is a number
1 - Yes, this is a number
W - Yes, this is an alphabet.
H - Yes, this is an alphabet.
( - No, this is not a number or alphabet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char misc[5];

    misc[0] = '4';
    misc[1] = '1';
    misc[2] = 'W';
    misc[3] = 'H';
    misc[4] = '(';
    misc[5] = '\0';

    size_t length = sizeof(misc)/sizeof(misc[0]);

    for(int a; a < length; a++)
    {
        printf("%c", misc[a]);
    }

    printf("\nSize of Array: %d\n", length);

    for(int i; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (misc[i] >= '0' && misc[i] <= '9')
        {
            printf("%c - ", misc[i]);
            printf("Yes, this is a number\n");
        }
        else if ((misc[i] >= 'a' && misc[i] <= 'z') || (misc[i] >= 'A' && misc[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("%c - Yes, this is an alphabet.\n", misc[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c - ", misc[i]);
            printf("No, this is not a number or alphabet\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thing: you indext `misc[5]` which is one to many. You defined it as `char misc[5]` which ranges from `0` to `4`

Comment: I only see one for-loop. Is there something you forgot?

Comment: Undefined behaviour caused by use of non-initialised `i` (and by ... see comment by Cediwelli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had one out of bounds error (off-by-one) for the length of the Array.
Also you did not initilize the `int a` with 0. The code below works for me.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    size_t length = 6;
    char misc[length]; // 6 not 5

    misc[0] = '4';
    misc[1] = '1';
    misc[2] = 'W';
    misc[3] = 'H';
    misc[4] = '(';
    misc[5] = '\0'; // not out of bounds anymore

    for(int a = 0; a < length; a++) // Initilize with 0 here
    {
        printf("%c", misc[a]);
    }

    printf("\nSize of Array: %d\n", length);

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) // Initilize with 0 here, too
    {
        if (misc[i] >= '0' && misc[i] <= '9')
        {
            printf("%c - ", misc[i]);
            printf("Yes, this is a number\n");
        }
        else if ((misc[i] >= 'a' && misc[i] <= 'z') || (misc[i] >= 'A' && misc[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("%c - Yes, this is an alphabet.\n", misc[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c - ", misc[i]);
            printf("No, this is not a number or alphabet\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are also using `i` without ever initialising it, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Bro, I am so dumb :D I forgot to edit the error out here after copying the original... thanks#

Comment: Replace `for(int i; i<length; i++)` with `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behaviour. That is practically the end of the explanation.

- (as pointed out by Cediwelli) you access beyond the highest legal index 4 of the array `misc`
- you are using `i` without ever initialising it